# Phaser, make a button click event continuous

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser.js to create a map (tileSprite) and have some sprites on it, because not all the sprites can get in, I'm using the camera to pan right and left.

I want the user to either click a keyboard key (left or right) or a directional button sprite to continuously pan the camera until the user releases the control.

I've implemented keyboard panning similar to [this example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/camera/moving-the-camera), I hold down a key and the camera moves/pans (10 pixels to each side on an event) and stops on key release.

However, when I've tried to implement the same thing using the 2 sprite buttons, each button fired only 1 event and panned the camera only 10 pixels per click. I need to to keep firing until I let go of the key.

```
var panRightButton = game.add.button(800, 5, 'right_pan_btn', onClickAction, this);
    panRightButton.onInputOver.add(onButtonOver, this);
    panRightButton.onInputOut.add(onButtonOut, this);
    panRightButton.onInputDown.add(panScreenRight, this);

    function panScreenRight() {
        game.camera.x += 10;
    }
```

I've tried using a boolean flag (`isPanning`) that would turn to true if i'm clicking a button and false on release. and have a while loop on `game.camera.x += 10;`, but it just slowed and stopped the script.

```
function onClickAction() {
     isPanning = true;
}

function onButtonOut() {
      isPanning = false;
}

function onButtonUp() {
      isPanning = false;
}

function panScreenLeft() {
    if (isPanning) {
         game.camera.x -= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do it is on the `update` method, but not within a loop. Using a flag to know if the button is being pressed is ok, but just let Phaser to update the camera position, like in the example that you have linked:

```
function update() {

    //...

    if (isPanningLeft) {
        game.camera.x -= 10;
    } else if (isPanningRight) {
        game.camera.x += 10;
    }

   //...
}
```

You don't need a loop because the `update` method is executed within a loop (and it is expected to be executed once by frame)